# DNS resolving incorrectly for some countries

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

European visitors are being served an old version of the website - because it appears they are getting a site that is resolving to an ipv6 address.

Other countries resolve to the correct ipv4 IP.

My understanding of DNS routing is fairly limited - where can I fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too narrow in scope for the answers to be of use to the wider Internet community.

Comment: Thanks,  have edited the question to make is more general.

Comment: That's not really a good edit. The problem was not that some "countries" were being served a different version of your web site, but that anyone who had IPv6 was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shopify doesn't support IPv6 (which may be a big problem for you later) so just remove the old AAAA record. Your DNS records appear to be hosted by "Web-2u Limited".